# Check if string can be converted to a decimal

Tags: string, type-conversion, decimal, ballerina

I want to convert a decimal to a string and see if the conversion was successful.

```
string d;
if (<decimal>d) ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [`fromString()` function from the decimal lang lib](https://lib.ballerina.io/ballerina/lang.decimal/0.0.0/functions#fromString) you can convert a string into a decimal. If the string cannot be converted, an error will be returned.

You can either use the [`check` expression](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/check-expression/) to return the error if the string cannot be converted to a decimal.

```
function convertToDecimal(string s) returns error?
    decimal d = check decimal:fromString("1.234");
    io:println(d);
}
```

Or you can use a union type `decimal|error` if you want to handle the error manually.
Use the [`is` operator](https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/unions/) to check if it is an error or not.

```
function convertToDecimal(string s) {
    decimal|error d = decimal:fromString(s);
    if(d is decimal) {
       // Handle the relevant logic where the decimal conversion is successful.
    } else {
       // Handle the logic if `d` is an error.
    }
    
}
```